# nil value reading settings.bundle

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

In the Settings.bundle file in Resources group, so far, I have only a PSGroupSpecifier and inside a PSMultiValueSpecifier with this XML code:

```
     <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>First day of week</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>firstDayOfWeek</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>Sunday</string>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <string>Sunday</string>
            <string>Monday</string>
        </array>
        <key>Titles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Sunday</string>
            <string>Monday</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I get the value, but firstDayOfWeek always returns nil value, can you see any mistake in the code?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *firstDayOfWeek = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstDayOfWeek"];
NSLog(@"FIRST DAY OF WEEK: %@", firstDayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any key for `firstDayOfWeek`.
"firstDayOfWeek" is the object for key `Key`.

The argument string of `objectForKey` must be a key in the plist `<key>yourKey</key>`

Try:

```
<key>firstDayOfWeek</key>
<string>DefaultValue</string>
```

Comment: I don't get it, isn't it like this: <key>Key</key><string>firstDayOfWeek</string>. Could you post the code? In the Apple developer sample it is like this.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AppPrefs/Introduction/Intro.html